# CV for tenure-track application: not sure whether to include Master's thesis

Tags: mathematics, application, cv, tenure-track

I was wondering about whether I should include/mention my Master's thesis in my CV. This doesn't count as a publication, since it was not published, and it's also not an original contribution. Thus, it doesn't belong to the "Publications" sections.

So where should I put it? Should I put the title in the point where I describe my Master's degree? Should I simply forget about it and let it go?

Comment: Do you have a section for theses?

Comment: Not really. I only put my PhD thesis title in the "Education/Employment" Section. I was thinking of also putting the Master's thesis there, but I've already heard too many times that in an academic CV, too many things can actually be detrimental.

Comment: I understand! My advisor lists his theses in a section by themselves. I listed mine under the "Education" section. To be honest, I feel that they belong to the "Education" section.

Comment: I agree with the above comment and would put it into the "Education" section. It seems fitting to see where you did your Master's and then see the topic of your thesis right there after the name of the university.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a section for theses and list both your MSc and PhD theses titles there. Or put it under Education.

(As a sidenote: you worry too much about style. What's important in a CV is the *content*, not so much the *style*.)

Comment: I wouldn't agree with your sidenote.  Good style is what helps get people to *read* your content.

Comment: I'm not going to disagree, but whether you have a section "Theses" or include it in "Other works" or include the titles of your theses in the "education section" really doesn't make any difference :-)